# Как реализовать в функциональном стиле то, что в ооп пичется с помощью наследований?

Tags: функциональное-программирование

Хотелось бы, при разработке проекта, использовать функциональный подход, но возник вопрос: как перенести концепцию вынесения функционала некоторых схожих сущностей под средством наследования в функциональный подход, или же понять, как схожая задача решается в фп языках. Допустим, есть набор некоторых устройств с которыми взаимодействует система. При использовании ООП, логично представлять каждое устройство классом, методами, перечень его возможных действий, и полями его состояния. Так же, что важно, множества устройств могут иметь схожий функционал, который не меняется и различается по некоторым признакам, что так же логично представляется наследованием. Как такие абстракции представляются в ФП? Дело в том, что концепция erlang очень заманчиво выглядит для использования в моем проекте. Хотелось бы ознакомиться и понять концепцию ФП во всех деталях, как бы я смог реализовать те же вещи что я делал на ооп.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую к функциональному программированию это не относится, но функциональные языки могут предоставлять похожие механизмы. Например, в `Haskell` для этих целей используются классы типов.

Для сравнения на равенство экземпляров одного и того же типа мы используем оператор `==`. Очевидно, что логика сравнения чисел будет отличаться от логики сравнения, например, деревьев. Поэтому оператор `==` выносится в отдельный класс типов `Eq`.

```hs
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

И любой тип, для которого мы хотим реализовать возможность сравнения, объявляется его представителем.

```hs
instance Eq Int where
  (==) = ...

instance Eq Tree where
  (==) = ...
```

Например у нас есть тип с двумя полями `String` и `Int`. Делаем его представителем `Eq`

```hs
data MyType = MyData String Int deriving Show

instance Eq MyType where
  MyData string1 int1 == MyData string2 int2 =
    string1 == string2 && int1 == int2
```

Так как `Int` и `String` (это синоним для `[Char]`) уже являются представителями `Eq` с ними мы можем использовать `==` ничего не объявляя отдельно.

Теперь можно сравнивать экземпляры `MyType`

```hs
Prelude> MyData "xyz" 123 == MyData "xyz" 123
True
Prelude> MyData "xyz" 123 == MyData "zyx" 321
False
```

Теперь можем определить оператор сравнения на неравенство `!=` таким образом

```hs
(!=) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
a != b = not (a == b)
```

Это полиморфный оператор, он принимает два однотипных операнда, обязательно являющихся представителями `Eq`, и возвращает результат их сравнения на неравенство.

```hs
Prelude> MyData "xyz" 123 != MyData "xyz" 321
True
Prelude> "abc" != "abc"
False
```

> Стоит отметить, что в стандартной библиотеке оператор сравнения на неравенство называется `/=` и также является методом класса типов `Eq`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Интересно будет найти в elixir(erlang) что то похожее.

Comment: @KazakovAnt в `Elixir` нечто похожее реализуется с помощью [протоколов](https://elixirschool.com/ru/lessons/advanced/protocols/).

Comment: Классы типов в Haskell очень далеки от классов ООП

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Я не утверждал обратного. Вопрос был (по крайней мере так я его понимаю) о возможности писать полиморфный код в функциональных языках. Я описал (хоть и явно не обозначил чтобы не перегружать ответ) два типа полиморфизма в `Haskell` - специальный (`Ad-hoc polymorphism`) в операторе `==` и параметрический (`Parametric polymorphism`) в операторе `!=`.

Comment: @extrn,  я не говорил (и не пытался сказать)  что Вы это утверждали :) Это был комментарий для автора вопроса. А Вы,  по моим наблюдениям,  достаточно опытный человек,  чтобы не допустить такой ошибки :))

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов В любом случае, стоило сказать об этом побольше, например о том, что наследования типов данных в `Haskell` нет. И не получится, например, сложить в один список экземпляры разных типов, но реализующие один и тот же класс типов, как это можно было бы сделать в `Java`: `Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>())`. Но опять же - не хотелось раздувать ответ. Так что спасибо за комментарий, наверняка кому-нибудь пригодится. :)